# Video recorded using Kurento is corrupted

Tags: android, ffmpeg, webrtc, kurento

We are using Kurento media server v6.6.1 to record a video conference. The web app client which runs on Chrome(Windows, OSX, Android) is using a modified version of one-to-one-call-advanced Kurento sample and the second client is an Android native application which is using Nubomedia webrtcpeer v1.1.1. Nubomedia webrtcpeer uses LibJingle built by io.pristine v11139(released on December 2015). The video and audio is recorded in two separate recorder endpoints by Kurento.

Video conference recordings generated using web app client/s are working properly. But sometimes the video generated using native application contains all the frames within initial few seconds. Please find below download link for the problematic video generated by our Android native application,

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1vOVk8hPuP_iOlQfsmMoqZLhICy-Jpcee/view?usp=sharing

We are testing this feature on a range of Android devices, Nexus 5(Android 6.0.1), Nexus 6(Android 7.1.1), Sony Xperia Z Tablet(Android 6.0.1), Samsung Galaxy Tab A(Android 5.0), OnePlus 3(Android 7.1.1), Xiaomi A1(Android 7.1.1). The issue randomly starts occurring on a bunch of these devices while the others work properly and vice-versa.

We are recording the videos with the following constraints,

Web app client

Minimum video width: 32
Minimum video height: 32
Maximum video width: 320
Maximum video height: 320
Minimum framerate: 1
Maximum framerate: 15
Video container format: MP4
Video codec: H.264
Audio codec: AAC

Android native client

Minimum video width: 32
Minimum video height: 32
Maximum video width: 480
Maximum video height: 640
Minimum framerate: 1
Maximum framerate: 25
Video container format: MP4
Video codec: H.264
Audio codec: Opus